# How to align Textinput inputs on same flex row in react native ? (dynamically)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to set two textInputs on same row , named set 1  and set 2

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
<Text style={styles.label}style= {{width : 100}}>Expiration date</Text>
    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputdate} />  
    </View>

      <Text style={styles.label}>CVV</Text>
   <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
      <TextInput  style={styles.inputcvv } maxLength={17} />
  </View>
```

Please send me the css paticulat, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want your label and the `TextInput` in a line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454132/3597276

Answer (score 5):

If you want your labels and `TextInputs` in the same line the code will be like this:

```
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View  style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text style={{flex: 0}}>Expiration date</Text>
          <TextInput style={{flex: 1}} />  
        </View>

        <View  style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text style={{flex: 0}}>CVV</Text>
          <TextInput  style={{flex: 1}} maxLength={17} />
        </View>
      </View>
```